# Delay issue in displaying live chat box upon button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, livechat

I have implemented the following requirement:

1) Initially  a contact us button.
2) Upon clicking one window with 3 options will come
3) one of them is to show live chat box(like phplive chat/ zenduslive chat etc) by hiding the existing window.

But the problem is that, after clicking the submit button by selecting the live chat radio button option, it is taking some time to show live chat box after the exsiting window gets hiddden. What I need is to reduce the time delay between showing live chat widget and closing the window with radio button options. Also upon submitting the button, live chat showuld be visible in such a way that "a window that actually had the login form to type the question".

Eg of live chat : http://livechat.mirrormx.net/

## SNIPPET CODE:

```
(function( $ ) {
$('#submit').click(function(){
var selValue = $('input[name=chat-options]:checked').val(); 

   if (selValue == "form-one") {
      $("#contacts-popup-link").click();
    } else if (selValue == "form-two") {
       $("#contacts-popup-link1").click();
       } else if (selValue == "live-chat") {
       $("#loader").show();
       $("#text-7").fadeOut(1700, "swing");  // hiding the window contatining 
         $.getScript("//testwebsite.com/livechat/php/app.php?widget-init.js"); //loading the live chat using this url
        }
});
```

==============================================

`<div id="customer-chat-widget" class="customer-chat customer-chat-widget contact-form">`  - normal chat box without window have form type question.

`<div id="customer-chat-widget" class="customer-chat customer-chat-widget contact-form customer-chat-visible">`  - a window that actually had the form to type the question(auto popup on each time user see the chat)

Thanks

Comment: `Eg of live chat` is that where your code is?

Comment: do you understand `$("#text-7").fadeOut(1700, "swing");`? takes 1.7 seconds to fade out?

Comment: `after clicking the submit button` - is this a form submit? have you prevented normal form submit behaviour, or do you require normal form submit behaviour?

Comment: Hello Jaromanda X, I will show you the code now. Initially i set #text-7 hidden using hide function. Then it will disappear then it will take time to load live chat box

Comment: Please see the code in this link: https://pastebin.com/0TYizmmX

Comment: yeah, you do realise the submit action on a form will load a new page (or the same page in your case as you have no action attribute on form) - is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: Yeah I think i need to prevent the submit action from reloading the page. Sir so how to fix the issue? I will do as per your suggestion... please

Comment: you'll need to **prevent** the **Default** behaviour of the **event** ?

Comment: i.e. `.click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); .... rest of your "code" ...})`

Comment: Yeah i updated the code, but still the page is getting loaded: Please see the updated link: https://pastebin.com/gRGF2DCD

Comment: Because upon loading the url using getScript function, it is taking time. The time is due to loading the url.

Comment: `it is taking time` - yes, loading from a server is never instantaneous (unless the response is already in cache of course)

Comment: Is there any fix for this sir? Also encountered one more issue while testing. The issue is that nothing works for a wordpress post.I have one wordpress post and it is not even alerting anything inside $('#submit').click(function(). Do you have any idea on these two..